# Change background when mouse goes hover a button

Tags: javascript, css, button, background, hover

i'm trying to change the background image of my homepage everytime that i pass the mouse on a button, for 5 different buttons.

I'm trying with Javascript but it seams not be working, any help?

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: what you have done? nobody gonna write code for you.

Comment: We need code please.

Comment: Code added, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here whenever you hover a paragraph the background image of the paragraph will change.

**HTML Code**

```
 <p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        }, function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
    });
```

Comment: And what in case i have to specify the name of the class where background-image is? It will be .et_pb_section_0

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code but nothing seems to happen;

```
$("et_pb_section_0").hover(function(){
        $(this).square0("background-color", "yellow");
        }, function(){
        $(this).square1("background-color", "pink");
    });
```

.et_pb_section_0 is the class of the background and .square0, .square1 are the buttons.

Thanks for helping.